# Prevent Dropdown menu from closing if I click a menu item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have a drop down menu in sidebar and it has links as menu items.
When I click a menu item(link) then link works fine but drop down menu gets closed.

But I want that dropdown menu stay opened even after clicking a menu item.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
     <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
     <div class="list-group list-group-flush">              
          <a href="{% url 'shop:admin_orders_list' %}">All orders</a>

          <button class="dropdown-btn button">Products
               <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>

          <div class="dropdown-container">
               <a href="{% url 'shop:admin_products_list' %}">View Products</a>
               <a href="{% url 'shop:admin_product_create' %}">Add New Product</a>
          </div>   
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried these two following ways:

```
$('div.dropdown-container a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

```
$('div.dropdown-container a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But these two ways did not work.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: It looks like you're loading a new page when the link is clicked, so what you're trying to do will not really be workable unless your site is using a Single Page Architecture approach, which I doubt given your question, as it would work automatically.

Comment: Plz, provide the complete code of the menu.

Comment: I have added complete code in question. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

try this make sure to put your dropdown id there

```
$('#dropdownid').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Great Save my time

Comment: Code does not work. Dropdown is still closing.

Comment: hi @JasmeetPabla  can put your code to jsfiddle or somewhere I can check

Comment: @mohamedruzaik I have added complete code in question. Please check that.

Comment: is your dropdown  working I checked your HTML and bootstrap classes but not looks like bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: @mohamedruzaik yes dropdown is working. I have not used bootstrap classes.